# How to create the full page cache (FPC) for the request with custom tag in magento?

Tags: full-page-cache

I need to create a cache for the request with tag "WORDPRESS_FPC".
I don't like the option of adding this tag to each block. Does anyone have other options or know how to clear the full page cache for the request?

I've already added cache type:

```
<!--app/code/local/Mod/Wordpress/etc/config.xml-->
    <global>
        <cache>
            <types>
                <wordpress_full_page translate="label,description" module="mod_wordpress">
                    <label>Wordpress Page Cache</label>
                    <description>Wordpress full page caching.</description>
                    <tags>WORDPRESS_FPC</tags>
                </wordpress_full_page>
            </types>
        </cache>
    </global>
```

I've already added request to FPC:

```
<!--app/code/local/Mod/Wordpress/etc/config.xml-->
    <frontend>
        <cache>
            <requests>
                <wordpress>
                    <post>
                        <view>enterprise_pagecache/processor_default</view>
                    </post>
                </wordpress>
            </requests>
        </cache>
    </frontend>
```